# Coexisting navigation drawer and sliding pane layout

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer, slidingmenu

I would like to use the navigation drawer on the left for top level navigation and
the sliding pane layout on the right for the detail/main content browsing like in a classic 2 pane layout (multi pane).

Would you say this is a good idea in terms of usability / guidelines ?

Do you know existing apps doing this ?

Do you see the any technical issues i could face with it ?

Comment: got any solution for navigation-drawer and multipane ? it's hard nut to crack !